# Underscore template iteration with `tr` element on different datas giving wrong result

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

In my template, I have 5 headings, I am using "th" for that. and I would like to print two different datas underneath. for that i tried this but giving wrong out put...

any one help me to sort this pleae?

```
    <% _.each(obj.totalForMonths.totalformonths.monthData, function(item) { %> //data 1
                            <tr> //printing 3 tds
                                <td><%= item.month %></td>
                                <td><%= item.amount %></td>
                                <td><%= item.count %></td>

                            <%  }) %>

                            <% _.each(obj.totalForMonths.previousScheme.monthData, function(item) { //data 2 %>
//printing 2 tds!
                                    <td><%= item.amount %></td>
                                    <td><%= item.count %></td>

                            <%  }) %>

                            </tr>   //closing the tr after appended all 5
```

but it works as, first it loops all 3 and 2 loops separately. It gives ugly out put. How can i print all five within `tr` on each iterators?

Any one help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could merge the arrays "obj.totalForMonths.totalformonths.monthData" & "obj.totalForMonths.previousScheme.monthData" if they are of the same length:

```
    <% 
        var a = _.map(obj.totalForMonths.totalformonths.monthData, function(e){
            return [e.month, e.amount, e.count]
        });
        var b = _.map(obj.totalForMonths.previousScheme.monthData, function(e){
            return [e.amount, e.count]
        });
        rows = _.map(_.zip(a,b), function(e){
            return _.flatten(e)
        });
    %>
    <% _.each(rows, function(row) { %>
        <tr>
            <% _.each (row, function(column){ %>
                <td><%= column %></td>
            <% }) %>            
        </tr>
    <%  }) %>
```

Comment: can i use the `<%=index%>` instead of static number like 1,2,3. May be the dynamic data may varied than this is became an issue right?

Comment: yep (i updated the template) but you will need to edit the map functions if you need to include data other than (month, amount &count)

Comment: Yes it works!, But still a small issue is, I am getting the `td` in odd way. ( the last row has only 4 td instead of 5 )